# Reverse DNS lookup not working Centos 7 BIND

Tags: dns, centos

I'm setting up an Ansible lab and I thought it would be a good idea to use DNS. I'm using named (BIND) on Centos 7 and followed this guide for setting up DNS: https://www.unixmen.com/setting-dns-server-centos-7/.

My forward lookups are working fine. However, I'm not having any luck with my reverse lookups:

```
sam@gnome-desktop ~ $ host windows-7
windows-7.mylab.local has address 192.168.254.247
sam@gnome-desktop ~ $ host 192.168.254.247
Host 247.254.168.192.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Here's my /etc/named.conf and forward and reverse files in /var. Could someone pick up on obvious mistakes that I'm overlooking? Thanks!

```
[root@name-server ~]# cat /etc/named.conf 
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
// See the BIND Administrator's Reference Manual (ARM) for details about the
// configuration located in /usr/share/doc/bind-{version}/Bv9ARM.html

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 192.168.254.249;}; ## Master DNS IP ##
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.254.0/24;}; ## IP Range##

    /* 
     - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
     - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable 
       recursion. 
     - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access 
       control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
       cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification 
       attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
       reduce such attack surface 
    */
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

zone "mylab.local" IN {
type master;
file "forward.mylab";
allow-update { none; };
};

zone "254.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
type master;
file "reverse.mylab";
allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[root@name-server ~]# cat /var/named/forward.mylab 
$TTL 86400                                                                                           
@   IN  SOA     name-server.mylab.local. root.mylab.local. (                                             
    2011071001  ;Serial                                                                                   
    3600        ;Refresh                                                                                           
    1800        ;Retry                                                                                             
    604800      ;Expire                                                                                                    
    86400       ;Minimum TTL                                                                                               
)                                                                                                                                      
@       IN  NS         name-server.mylab.local.                                                                                        
@       IN  A           192.168.254.249                                                                                                       
@       IN  A           192.168.254.253                                                                                                              
@       IN  A           192.168.254.252                                                                                                                 
@       IN  A           192.168.254.251                                                                                                                       
@       IN  A           192.168.254.250                                                                                                                            
@       IN  A           192.168.254.248                                                                                                                              
@       IN  A           192.168.254.247                                                                                                                                    
name-server       IN  A   192.168.254.249                                                                                                                                      
gnome-desktop     IN  A   192.168.254.253
centos-ansible    IN  A   192.168.254.252
centos-7-node-1   IN  A   192.168.254.251
centos-7-node-2   IN  A   192.168.254.250
mint              IN  A   192.168.254.248
windows-7         IN  A   192.168.254.247
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[root@name-server ~]# cat /var/named/reverse.mylab 
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     name-server.mylab.local. root.mylab.local. (
    2011071001  ;Serial
    3600        ;Refresh
    1800        ;Retry
    604800      ;Expire
    86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
@       IN  NS          name-server.mylab.local.
@       IN  PTR         mylab.local.
name-server           IN  A   192.168.254.249
gnome-desktop         IN  A   192.168.254.253
centos-ansible        IN  A   192.168.254.252
centos-7-node-1       IN  A   192.168.254.251
centos-7-node-2       IN  A   192.168.254.250
mint                  IN  A   192.168.254.248
windows-7             IN  A   192.168.254.247
101     IN  PTR         name-server.mylab.local
102     IN  PTR         gnome-desktop.mylab.local
103     IN  PTR         centos-ansible.mylab.local
104     IN  PTR         centos-7-node-1.mylab.local
105     IN  PTR         centos-7-node-2.mylab.local
106     IN  PTR         mint.mylab.local
107     IN  PTR         windows-7.mylab.local
[root@name-server ~]#
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: In your reverse zone (and actually in any zonefile) any FQDN (like your `name-server.mylab.local` entry) needs to have a `.` at the end of the domain, so it should be `name-server.mylab.local.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your "reverse" zone file, one thing needs to be clarified:

All the `A` records in the reverse zone are completely useless, because reverse-DNS does not perform any magic inverse lookups. Your nslookup command *does not* try to find all domain names having the specified IP address. Nothing like that happens. Instead, reverse-DNS converts the IP address to a special domain, and then *only* does a plain `PTR` lookup for it.

So as you can see in your own nslookup output, the address `192.168.254.247` got converted to the special domain `247.254.168.192.in-addr.arpa.`. And that domain is not in your reverse zone file! You have a PTR record for 101, a 102, a 103... but you don't have a 247.

The record should look like this:

```
247     IN  PTR     windows-7.mylab.local.
```

The configured zone name, `254.168.192.in-addr.arpa`, will be added automatically. But you can also write it in full:

```
247.254.168.192.in-addr.arpa.     IN  PTR      windows-7.mylab.local.
```

---

(Don't forget that your PTR *target* needs the trailing `.`, otherwise it will have the zone name appended to it as well – you'll get results like `windows-7.mylab.local.254.168.192.in-addr.arpa.`)